# Converting XML to JSON in PHP with inline HTML elements

Tags: php, json, simplexml

I'm attempting to convert some XML to JSON in PHP using simplexml, but the conversion is leaving out inline HTML. I'm not sure the correct terminology for the inline HTML (embedded?), but below are some examples of what I'm doing and what I'm looking for:

An excerpt of the XML I'm trying to convert:

```
<uscDoc xsi:schemaLocation="http://xml.house.gov/schemas/uslm/1.0 USLM-1.0.15.xsd" xml:lang="en" identifier="/us/usc/t1" xmlns="http://xml.house.gov/schemas/uslm/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">
    <meta>
      <dc:title>Title 1</dc:title>
      <dc:type>USCTitle</dc:type>
      <docNumber>1</docNumber>
      <docPublicationName>Online@116-17</docPublicationName>
      <dc:publisher>OLRC</dc:publisher>
      <dcterms:created>2019-04-04T07:37:52</dcterms:created>
      <dc:creator>USCConverter 1.1</dc:creator>
    </meta>
    <main>
    <title id="id14e8bf81-56ce-11e9-9468-8af4f27dcc3b" identifier="/us/usc/t1"><num value="1">Title 1—</num><heading>GENERAL PROVISIONS</heading>
    <note topic="enacting" id="id14e90da2-56ce-11e9-9468-8af4f27dcc3b"><p>This title was enacted by <ref href="/us/act/1947-07-30/ch388">act July 30, 1947, ch. 388</ref>, § 1, <ref href="/us/stat/61/633">61 Stat. 633</ref></p></note>
    <note topic="miscellaneous" id="id14e95bc3-56ce-11e9-9468-8af4f27dcc3b"><p>Current through 116-17</p></note>
```

When I convert this to JSON (or to an array) in PHP, it results in the following:

```
Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [identifier] => /us/usc/t1
        )

    [meta] => Array
        (
            [docNumber] => 1
            [docPublicationName] => Online@116-17
        )

    [main] => Array
        (
            [title] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => id14e8bf81-56ce-11e9-9468-8af4f27dcc3b
                            [identifier] => /us/usc/t1
                        )

                    [num] => Title 1—
                    [heading] => GENERAL PROVISIONS
                    [note] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [topic] => enacting
                                            [id] => id14e90da2-56ce-11e9-9468-8af4f27dcc3b
                                        )

                                    [p] => This title was enacted by , § 1,
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [topic] => miscellaneous
                                            [id] => id14e95bc3-56ce-11e9-9468-8af4f27dcc3b
                                        )

                                    [p] => Current through 116-17
                                )

                        )
```

The portion that is incorrect (amongst other left-out data) is the section that includes the following: "This title was enacted by , § 1,"

When I convert this XML with an online javascript XML to JSON converter (http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/), it converts correctly:

```
{
  "uscDoc": {
    "-xsi:schemaLocation": "http://xml.house.gov/schemas/uslm/1.0 USLM-1.0.15.xsd",
    "-xml:lang": "en",
    "-identifier": "/us/usc/t1",
    "-xmlns": "http://xml.house.gov/schemas/uslm/1.0",
    "-xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "-xmlns:dc": "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/",
    "-xmlns:dcterms": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/",
    "meta": {
      "dc:title": "Title 1",
      "dc:type": "USCTitle",
      "docNumber": "1",
      "docPublicationName": "Online@116-17",
      "dc:publisher": "OLRC",
      "dcterms:created": "2019-04-04T07:37:52",
      "dc:creator": "USCConverter 1.1"
    },
    "main": {
      "title": {
        "-id": "id14e8bf81-56ce-11e9-9468-8af4f27dcc3b",
        "-identifier": "/us/usc/t1",
        "num": {
          "-value": "1",
          "#text": "Title 1—"
        },
        "heading": "GENERAL PROVISIONS",
        "note": [
          {
            "-topic": "enacting",
            "-id": "id14e90da2-56ce-11e9-9468-8af4f27dcc3b",
            "p": {
              "#text": [
                "This title was enacted by ",
                ", § 1, "
              ],
              "ref": [
                {
                  "-href": "/us/act/1947-07-30/ch388",
                  "#text": "act July 30, 1947, ch. 388"
                },
                {
                  "-href": "/us/stat/61/633",
                  "#text": "61 Stat. 633"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
```

As you can see, the "this title was enacted by" line is properly broken up so it can be interspersed with the data below it, including "act July 30, 1947, ch. 388" and "61 Stat. 633."

I've tried every option I can find in simplexml to get it to parse the XML in the way the online XML to JSON parser does, but I can't get it to work. I've tried countless other PHP code snippets I've found here and elsewhere, but can't get the same result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't complete XML.

Comment: SimpleXML is not designed for "blindly" (i.e. without specifying the expected structure) converting XML to another format, it's designed for extracting data and making small modifications to it. This is probably a case where you're better off using a different API, e.g. DOM, XMLReader, `xml_parser_create`, so that you have access to the full structure and can decide what output format you want.